# How to set a dependancy property from a style trigger

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a custom wpf control with the following style set. In the code behind I have a dependency property called selected. How do I set this property to true when OnMouseLeftButtonDown trigger is actioned?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:myControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:myControl}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseLeftButtonDown">
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF9B1111"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDown" SourceName="textBlock">
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseLeftButtonDown}"/>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDown" SourceName="textBlock2">
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseLeftButtonDown}"/>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Border Name="border" BorderBrush="#FFDEDEDE" BorderThickness="1" Margin="1" >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,1,2,3" Text="{TemplateBinding ElementName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF7C8CF1"  FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Name="textBlock2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,1,2,3" Text="{TemplateBinding ElementText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF75757A" FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Selected", typeof (bool), typeof (XliffElement), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

        public bool Selected
        {
            get { return (bool) GetValue(SelectedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedProperty, value); }
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this another way. I changed the names of the controls to PART_ElementName and PART_ElementText the I did the following in the OnApplyTemplate() method

```
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            _elementName = Template.FindName("PART_ElementName", this) as TextBlock;
            _elementText = Template.FindName("PART_ElementText", this) as TextBlock;

            if (_elementName != null) _elementName.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, args) => SelectControl();
            if (_elementText != null) _elementText.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, args) => SelectControl();
        }
```

Then I do the changes in the SelectControl() method

Answer (score 0):

In your `Storyboard` *OnMouseLeftButtonDown* you can add `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames`. Sample:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseLeftButtonDown">
    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF9B1111"/>
    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    <!-- xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" -->
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="YouTarget" Storyboard.TargetProperty="NameOfYourProperty">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

For attached dependency properties have to write so:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(local:YourDependecyClass.IsSampleMyProperty)"
```

Comment: Ok so in my case what would "YouTarget" be?

Comment: @John: To what source you set your property?

Comment: I was wanting it to happen when they click anywhere on the control.

Comment: @John: I mean, for what target do you want to to set your property. Where in XAML you set default value for your property?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. In the mean time I came up with an alternative way of doing this. Thanks very much for the effort its appreactated